# Increase session timeout for Classic ASP pages on Shared Azure websites (single instance)

Tags: azure, asp-classic, azure-web-app-service

- We have migrated a classic asp web site to Azure websites (shared
  mode single instance).
- We noticed that user sessions are timing out
  in 20 min and setting session.timeout = 120 programmatically not working.
- Any other settings that might help for classic asp pages on shared Azure websites?
- I tried setting session timeout in web.config (sessionState timeout="120") as well without any luck for classic asp pages. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

  ```
  <system.web>
   <sessionState timeout="120"/> 
  </system.web>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The web.config setting only affects ASP.NET. For Classic ASP you can globally set the timeout in the global.asa file, like this:

```
<script language="VBScript" runat="Server">
    Sub Session_OnStart
        Session.Timeout = 120
    End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: That particular web.config setting but there is no reason why you can't use `<session>` from the `<asp>` node in <system.webServer>`.